# GitHub Not Accessible for any browser

Tags: browser, git, connection, ssl, github

I can't access https://github.com/ website. I have try all browser. but, it is not run site. I get server not found error.

Why is not run Only github site?

Comment: Have you tried ping or traceroute to GitHub.com? And how about the SSL certificate status?

Comment: SSL certificate status is "identity not verify"

Comment: GitHub will drop IE support for Windows XP users on January 5, in the name of security (RC4). And on my machine, the root certificate org is "DigiCert", if not, you've already became the victim of Man-in-the-Middle attack.

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632672/github-not-accessible-for-any-browser)

Answer (score 1):

## WARNING: user3807124

The massive pipes of the interwebs may be proving too much for the poor black box in front of you. A malfunction of your web browser enchantment as you describe above can indicate any of the following:

1. You are a resident of the Supreme State of North Korea, which has recently been unable to access the interwebs despite the Supreme Leader's divine intervention. (though you do seem to be able to find your way onto superuser.com miraculously, so this is probably not the case)
2. You live in a Forbidden Kingdom with magical fiery walls in place to disrupt the flow of magic through the interweb tubes. Such enchantment-specific mystical obstruction does fit with your experience of a enchantment malfunction with `github.com` specifically. Do cast a location spell to determine your present bearings. Also, contacting your local `Interwebs & Spells Provisioner` (ISP) may help.
3. The interweb browsing enchantment you're using still has traces of past usage, and these lost shreds of magic are interfering with the passage of new mysticism into your black box. Consider [clearing this cache like so](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache).
4. All hope is lost for you, and the walls of reality are slowly closing, leaving you on the other side. Already, magic can no longer reach you from certain other black boxes because of the magic schism. Your [only hope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cc_h5Ghuj4) lies with your nearest magic box wizard/witch. Quickly step away from this magic box and contact a true expert in magic boxes for help.